# How can I omit the <h> tags out of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this code takes a website, and adds all the header information to a list. How can i modify the list so when the program prints, it shows every piece of the list on a separate line, and gets rid of the header tags?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
address = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp"
webPage = urlopen (address)

encoding = "utf-8"

list = []

for line in webPage:
    findHeader = ('<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>', '<h6>')
    line = str(line, encoding)
    for startHeader in findHeader:        
        endHeader = '</'+startHeader[1:]
        if (startHeader in line) and (endHeader in line):
            content = line.split(startHeader)[1].split(endHeader)[0]
            list.append(line)
            print (list)

webPage.close()
```

Comment: One issue with what you've currently written is that the begin/end header tags might be on different lines. Are we assuming that the html is always valid?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the HTML is valid or not, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using third-party packages, try BeautifulSoup to convert html into plain text. After you've got your *list*, you can remove `print (list)` from your loop and do this:

```
for e in list:
    # .rstrip() to remove trailing '\r\n'
    print(BeautifulSoup(e.rstrip(), "html.parser").text)
```

But don't forget to import BeautifulSoup first:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I assume you got bs4 installed, before running this example (pip3 install beautifulsoup4).

Also, you can use regular expressions to strip html tags. But it may be much more verbose and error-prone thing, than using html-parses like bs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't understand what you want to do.

But, for example you can easy collect all unique headers in dict:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

address = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp"
webPage = urlopen(address)

# get page content
response = str(webPage.read(), encoding='utf-8')

# leave only <h*> tags content
p = re.compile(r'<(h[0-9])>(.+?)</\1>', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
headers = re.findall(p, response)

# headers dict
my_headers = {}

for (tag, value) in headers:
    if tag not in my_headers.keys():
        my_headers[tag] = []

    # remove all tags inside
    re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', value)

    # replace few special chars
    value = value.replace('&lt;', '<')
    value = value.replace('&gt;', '>')

    if value not in my_headers[tag]:
        my_headers[tag].append(value)

# output
print(my_headers)
```

Output:

```
{'h2': ['The HTML <head> Element', 'Omitting <html> and <body>?', 'Omitting <head>', 'The HTML <title> Element', 'The HTML <style> Element', 'The HTML <link> Element', 'The HTML <meta> Element', 'The HTML <script> Element', 'The HTML <base> Element', 'HTML head Elements', 'Your Suggestion:', 'Thank You For Helping Us!'], 'h4': ['Top 10 Tutorials', 'Top 10 References', 'Top 10 Examples', 'Web Certificates'], 'h1': ['HTML <span class="color_h1">Head</span>'], 'h3': ['Example', 'W3SCHOOLS EXAMS', 'COLOR PICKER', 'SHARE THIS PAGE', 'LEARN MORE:', 'HTML/CSS', 'JavaScript', 'HTML Graphics', 'Server Side', 'Web Building', 'XML Tutorials', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'XML', 'Charsets']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for results without the header tags. You already have those values in your `content` variable, but instead of adding `content` to your list of results, you add `line`, which is the entire original line.

Next, you ask for each item printed on a new line. To do that, first remove the `print` statement inside your loop. That prints the *entire* list each time you add *one* result. Next, add new code at the bottom of the program, *outside* all the loops:

```
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

---

However, your technique of identifying headers in HTML isn't very robust. It expects pairs of opening and closing tags to be together on a single line. It also expects there to be no more than one header of any type on a single line. It expects  each opening tag has a matching closing tag. You can't rely on any of those things, even in *valid* HTML.

[Vrs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295632/33732) is on the right track suggesting Beautiful Soup, but rather than use it only for removing tags from the results, you can actually use it for *finding* the results, too. Consider the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

address = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp"
webPage = urlopen(address)

# The list of tag names we want to find
# Just the names, not the angle brackets    
findHeader = ('h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6')

soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage, 'html.parser')
headers = soup.find_all(findHeader)
for header in headers:
    print(header.get_text())
```

The `find_all` method accepts a list of tag names and returns `Tag` objects representing each result in document order. We store the list in `headers`, and the print the text of each one. The `get_text` method presents only the text portions of the tag, omitting not only the surrounding header tags, but also any embedded tags. (There are some embedded `span` tags in the page you're scraping, for example.)